# Hibernate-envers - Big decimal field is not audited correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, bigdecimal, hibernate-envers

I am using `Hibernate envers 5.2.10.Final` version to audit any changes on entity.
And in entity class, there is BigDecimal data type fields also exists (can't change to another data type like double because it needs to hold accurate precision)

Issue is that BigDecimal value is tracked as modified in audit table even when there is no change in value

Let's Say 0 (old value) and 0.00(new value) is tracked as modified and this is accepted but after stripping zeros means new value also 0 and this is also tracked as modified by hibernate envers.

I tired few options as below but no use

```
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Entity
class SomeEntity {
private Long id;
private BigDecimal value;
//getters and setters
}
```

And Say there is some class that sets value

```
class SomeClass{
Public void method(Foo foo) {
...//First approach
SomeEntity someEntity=newSomeEntity();
someEntity.setId(foo.getId());
someEntity.setValue(foo.getValue().stripTrailingZeros()); //still BigDecimal is tracked as modified in audit table

//Second approach
DecimalFormat decimalFormat.format("0.##");
SomeEntity someEntity=newSomeEntity();
someEntity.setId(foo.getId());
someEntity.setValue(new BigDecimal(decimalFormat(foo.getValue()))); //still BigDecimal is tracked as modified in audit table
//save to db
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BigDecimalTypeDescriptor#areEqual` considers two `BigDecimal` objects as equal if `compareTo` returns `0`, which is the case for `0` and `0.00`. So if you want to treat this kind of value change as a real value change, you will have to override the `JavaTypeDescriptor` for `BigDecimal` and also replace `org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType` with a new version that uses that new `JavaTypeDescriptor`.

Comment: Thank you Christian Beikov for the hint :) Can you please provide some code sample.. Thank you again

Comment: This is a very advanced topic and you might have to play around a bit, but essentially, you will have to create a subtype of `BigDecimalTypeDescriptor` with an overridden `areEqual` method. Then create a custom `TypeContributor` where you register a custom `BasicType`, for which you can copy `BigDecimalType`, but you use your new `BigDecimalTypeDescriptor` instead. Overall, I would advise you against this as it makes not much sense IMO, but if you *really* want this, you should try to figure out the rest from what I explained so far, so you understand what is happening.